# Is it safe to use the Attributes collection to store extra data?

Tags: asp.net, attributes

Is it safe to use the attributes collection of a web control to store extra data?

e.g.

```
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.Attributes.Add("ExtraData", "SomeData");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend against it as these attributes may be prone to tampering.  Instead, you should have a list of objects on the server in which each object stores both the drop down text data as well as the extra data in it.

You can then use the index of the drop down to determine which object in your list on the server is selected.  Typically, frontend controls should never contain anything but display data and indexes if you can help it.  This is why datagrids have a data index column, so you can retrieve the index of the record that corresponds to the row.  The record itself is not stored in the grid, only its fields are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

It will (most probably) safely arrive at the browser, but everything can be altered there. So anything you get back from the browser cannot be relied upon unless you sign it properly e.g. with a hash of your data + a secret.

With something like:

```
HASH_FUNCTION(DATA + SECRET), DATA
```

you can check on the server if somebody has tampered with your data.

Comment: I've found another way to accomplish what i was after but that is good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! But only if your data isn't sensitive and it doesn't matter if a client tampers with it. HTML 5 officially recognizes the use of data-* attributes for general purpose data. Mind you the data-* attributes are mostly used for client side stuff; they can also be used server side. But remember, only store non-sensitive data.

I've personally used data-* attributes in asp.net to simplify the client side process of displaying warning messages for links/buttons (such as a delete) button. The message can then be changed server side as needed by accessing the appropriate data-* attribute in the Attributes collection. If the client tampers with these attributes, it only hurts the client in that they may not get the warning message.